Writing graduate,undergraduate or research level math textbooks?
I know that writing textbooks is an art in itself, as opposed to writing research papers.    Where can I find a good source for learning to write this type of book at the undergraduate, postgraduate, or even research level?

There are ample of resources in terms of books, courses , workshop materials and so on. Well, Google might help in finding better results but a couple of recommendations are given below:

Writing Successful Textbooks by Anthony Haynes
The Elements of Academic Style: Writing for the Humanities by Eric Hayot
National Association Science Writers has some workshop materials, you need to sign up on their website to access them.
Purdue Online Writing lab offer some courses
...


Steven Krantz wrote a book called A Primer of Mathematical Writing: Being a Disquisition on Having Your Ideas Recorded, Typeset, Published, Read, and Appreciated, and in it, he talks about publishing math textbooks (as well as other mathematical writing). Krantz has written dozens of math textbooks and so has a ton of experience on the topic.
Apparently, Krantz' Primer is available on the arXiv.
